# Thread saftey and XMLSerializer

Tags: thread-safety, xmlserializer

Should a call to XmlSerializer.Serialize and XmlSerializer.Create be wrapped in a locked object for thread safety?

e.g.

```
var fileLock = new object();
lock (fileLock)
{
     // Serialize here
}
```

Comment: Are you concerned whether `XmlSerializer` is itself thread safe, or are you concerned about something else, say file write contention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> **Thread Safety**
>
> This type is thread safe.

So you should not need this lock.